# How to delete all rows from certain row to the LastRow?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I do not need to clear blank cells or anything. Just need to delete data from Row 800 to the Last Row.

My current code is as below, but it keeps return Range Not Found. How do I do it?

```
  function DeleteOld() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
    spreadsheet.getRange('800:lastRow').activate();
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 
    spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());
  Logger.log('Data Before 1990 deleted') 
  };
```

I tested the getLastRow function to see its number.

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
Logger.log(spreadsheet.getLastRow())   };
```

The return is `"12344.0"` If I changed the code to `getRange('800:12344")`, it works well. If `getRange('800:12344.0')`, returns error.

Since the return of the `getLastRow` hass decimal point, could it be the reason? and How do I fix that?

Comment: If you are actually using your showing script, `'800:lastRow'` of `spreadsheet.getRange('800:lastRow').activate();` is just the string of `800:lastRow`. In this case, `lastRow` is not used as the variable. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. So, how about modifying from `'800:lastRow'` to `'800:' + lastRow`?

Comment: Thanks. I tried
`spreadsheet.getRange('800' + lastRow).activate();`    But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, I got it wrong. 
`spreadsheet.getRange('800:' + lastRow).activate();`
This works perfectly!  Thank you so much. @Tanaike

Comment: Just a quick one.   What does the + mean here? @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `+` in this case, it is used for concatenating the strings. By the way, when your question is resolved, can you post it as an answer. By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.